# ms access: Enter parameter value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to open a form on click of a button. Below is my code

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()
    Dim stuff As String
    Dim salaryStatus As String
    stuff = "Senior Stuff"
    salaryStatus = "Deposit"
    sSQL = "SELECT CustomerT.* FROM CustomerT WHERE (((CustomerT.[Salary Status])=" & salaryStatus & ") AND ((CustomerT.[Stuff Type])= " & stuff & "));"

    DoCmd.OpenForm "clusterF"
    Forms!ClusterF.Form.RecordSource = sSQL
    Forms!ClusterF.Form.Requery
    Forms!ClusterF.Form.Refresh
End Sub
```

When I click on the button I get a small popup window says that `Enter parameter value stuff and salaryStatus`. Why does this window shows. What is wrong with my sql query and how to fix it?

Comment: That is a lot of unnecessary work. Have a look at the WHERE argument of OpenForm. If you insist on going the long way round, setting the recordsource automatically re-queries and there is no need to refresh. You have not quoted string data, nor have you worried about contained quotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, reduce it a little and do rename your button:

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()

    Dim stuff        As String
    Dim salaryStatus As String

    stuff = "Senior Stuff"
    salaryStatus = "Deposit"
    sSQL = "SELECT CustomerT.* FROM CustomerT WHERE CustomerT.[Salary Status] = '" & salaryStatus & "' AND CustomerT.[Stuff Type] = '" & stuff & "';"

    DoCmd.OpenForm "clusterF"
    Forms!ClusterF.RecordSource = sSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: An anonymous downvote for a correct answer? Interesting.